# Which classes of functions are "convolution ideals"?

Tags: convolution

- If $g$ is continuous then $f*g$ is continuous.
- If $g$ is smooth then $f*g$ is smooth.
- If $g$ is a polynomial then $f*g$ is a polynomial.

If **just one** of the two functions belongs to the class of well-behaved functions, then so does their convolution.  And each of the classes of functions above is an algebra.

Thus continuous functions, smooth functions, and polynomial functions are three "convolution ideals".  I have no idea whether that usage is consistent with standard conventions, although Google tells me the term "convolution ideal" is out there being used sometimes to refer to something.

To make the bulleted list of assertions into precise theorems, you'd probably have hypotheses about certain functions being integrable, etc.

**Are there any characterizations or classifications** or the like **of** classes of functions that behave like those in the three examples above?

Comment: I prefer "closed under convolution".  If the set of functions combined with convolution were an algebra (commutative semigroup?), you would be looking for the subalgebras of this universal algebra.  Gerhard "Do You Seek This Generality?" Paseman, 2015.07.16

Comment: @GerhardPaseman : But "closed under convolution" is not the same thing.  I'm not talking about classes of functions for which if two functions belong to it, then so does their convolution.  Rather this is about classes of functions for which if just one of the two belongs, then so does their convolution.  Each of my examples is also an algebra, although I didn't mention that above. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah yes.  I was not paying enough attention.  Ideal would be appropriate, although I might still prefer "absorbing set".  However, the literature I know talks only about things like left-absorbing elements b (ab=b).  Gerhard "Seeks Something Even More General" Paseman, 2015.07.16

Comment: The class of probability densities is closed under convolution, but is NOT an example of the sort above: If you convolve an arbitrary function with a probability density, you don't generally get a probability density. Nor do probability densities form an algebra.

Comment: Could you please clarify what domain your functions are defined on? In the context of harmonic analysis on noncommutative groups convolving a continuous function with an integrable one _on the wrong_ side can result in a discontinuous functio

Comment: One has the concept of being a module over the group algebra $L^1(G)$, but I don't know if that is too specific for what you are after

Comment: @YemonChoi : I had in mind $\mathbb R$ or $[0,\infty)$ or $\mathbb R^n$ or whichever generalizations might be interesting. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Given a function space, there is the notion of the multiplier algebra and of the convolution algebra: these are spaces of distributions which fix the given function space under convolution. Under Fourier transform multipliers go over to convolvers, and conversely. All this makes sense inside the algebra of tempered distributions.

Comment: @PeterMichor : What do you mean by "fix the given function space under convolution"?  Do you mean the space is closed under convolution?  But how would a particular algebra "close" it under convolution if that's what is meant? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @YemonChoi: Could you perhaps give a reference or more details concerning the discontinuous convolutions you mentioned?

Comment: @LutzMattner I'm afraid I don't have the reference to hand, but if you take a non-unimodular group $G$ with left-invariant Haar measure $\lambda$, and take $h\in L^1(G,\lambda)$ and $f\in L^1(G,\lambda)$, assume $f$ is continuous (but not nec bounded) and try to show that $h*f$ is continuous, I think the "natural proof" breaks down, and probably one can then cook up a counterexample with some kind of sliding hump argument

Comment: @LutzMattner Sorry, in the above it should be $f*h$, not $h*f$. The idea is that $h$ is an average of translations, but right translation is bad for $\lambda$, so convolving with $h$ on the right can cause "problems to pile up"

Comment: I notice that functions having bounded support are _not_ such an "ideal".